# C# - RTP screen streaming

Tags: c#, stream, screen, share, rtp

I'm trying to make a remote desktop app where user controls his pc from a webapp (as in logmein).
I achieved that with C# for the desktop part, and NodeJS for the webapp, the communication was made using Socket.IO.

My first attempt was capturing the screenshot (only 5 fps), then comparing it to the previous screenshot and sending only the difference in 8-bit image color which resulted - in a 800 * 600 resolution virtual desktop - in a 100kb first image, then from 5kb to 60Kb depending on the changes on the screen.

With my local machine controlling a virtualbox, everything was perfect, but when I hosted the webapp online, the result was catastrophic, an improbable lag was taking place.

After a few researches It turned out this kind of app was impossible to achieve with my way, and that I have to use a real-time protocol and make a live streaming out of the client screen.

My questions are :

- Is there any free / open-source RTP libraries that is ready-to-use ?
- How would-I transfer a live streaming from the desk app to the webapp since it's coming from the client side which has no open port ? I was thinking of another desktop app that will run on the server (hosting the webapp) and then it will stream the same content again, and then the webapp can simply display the content by acceding to the local ip with the RTP port, but this doesn't solve the mystery of transferring a live streaming from the client to the server ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any free / open-source RTP libraries that is ready-to-use ?

- [live555](http://www.live555.com/liveMedia/) - I've used and is excellent, but C++ so you would have to interop.
- [gstreamer](https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/) - also native requiring interop.
- [Managed Media Aggregation](https://net7mma.codeplex.com/) I've not used but it is completely managed.

> How would-I transfer a live streaming from the desk app to the webapp
>   since it's coming from the client side which has no open port ? I was
>   thinking of another desktop app that will run on the server (hosting
>   the webapp) and then it will stream the same content again, and then
>   the webapp can simply display the content by acceding to the local ip
>   with the RTP port, but this doesn't solve the mystery of transferring
>   a live streaming from the client to the server ?

This would be tricky. All the libraries above follow strict RTSP/RTP specification which requires opening a listening port on your host side, which is undoubtedly going to be behind a nat'd address. I would stick with each end being a client and reaching 'up' to your webservice. You also need to guarantee delivery of your frames (because your delivering incremental deltas) so RTP (which is traditionally over UDP) would be challenging.

**Some thoughts**

At the end of the day RTP is just a standardized 12 byte header and packetization rules for compressed media. It's not going to help with latency. The real benefit would allow you to connect to the endpoint with in a standards compliant way, like with a [VLC](https://www.videolan.org/) client.

You could tune your sockets and that will help a bit but what I would focus on to be honest is compression and screen capture efficiency. What image compression are you using? VNC has traditionally used zlib and some others lossy like jpeg. The smaller you get those frames the better.

Also another thought which may help - Microsoft has an API for getting 'dirty screen areas'. It is called [Desktop Duplication API](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/hh404487(v=vs.85).aspx) and it performs incredibly fast. It is Win8 and up however.

All the best on your endeavor!

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer, I have some questions though, when you sayd **I would stick with each end being a client and reaching 'up' to your webservice.** , do you mean the client that is capturing the screenshots reaching the webservice ? So no RTP ? And based on your second part of the comment, the RTP is not really helpful, there isn't something special about it about the latency, right ? So I might just well stick with my current method and focus on the compression / screenshots ? (To be followed)

Comment: Currently I'm taking screenshots manually since I have read that DPA does not support Win7 I believe, and i'm not using any compression methods because I tried zlib and it was taking too much time to compress, and I tried lz4net which was super fast but the result was not much satisfying (60kb image becomes 50kb), what do you think ?

Comment: I forgot to mention that my current screenshot execution time is ~.05s
Edit: The whole process of capturing the screen, checking for difference between current and previous screenshot and saving the difference bitmap takes ~.1s  up to ~.13s , it's a bit too much I believe, I will give the DDA a try

Comment: What I mean is each end of your application (sender and viewer) could connect to some service running off a public server. This isn't necessary, this was just a thought to not have to worry about opening listening socket and worry about your public addressing. You could stay point to point, but your server's address must be well known and accessible.

Comment: zlib is slow, but it should be able to get you at least 10fps, maybe more depending on the size of the regions. JPEG compression would be much faster and smaller. VNC for instance uses zlib and jpeg.

Comment: There's another problem actually, using DDA, it takes 0.23s to capture my desktop which use a full hd wallpaper with a resolution of 1920 * 1080 (3.5Mb), is there a way to change the wallpaper or something to avoid this issue ?

Comment: Actually, the JPEG compression is awesome :O I just tried it and it reduces the size of my desktop (with 10% quality level) to 70kb, and with lz4net it reduces to 46kb, in a time of .02s

Comment: Yes it really is. And not all jpeg compressors are created equal. By far the fastest I’ve tested is libjpeg-turbo: https://libjpeg-turbo.org/About/TurboJPEG.